# Ionic 2 google signin with firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

im getting some troubles with firebase authentication and google provider. Im trying to signin with google provider (this works fine) but then i want to redirect to my homepage but im getting something wrong.

I have an auth provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase';


@Injectable()
export class AuthData {
  // Here we declare the variables we'll be using.
  public fireAuth: any;
  googleProvider: any;

  constructor() {
    this.fireAuth = firebase.auth(); // We are creating an auth reference.

    // Google Provider for Google Auth
    this.googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  }

  /**
   * This function doesn't take any params, it just logs the current user out of the app.
   */
  logoutUser(): any {
    return this.fireAuth.signOut();
  }

  /**
   * This function doesn't take any params, it just signin the current user
   * using google provider.
   */
  googleSignin(): any {
    return this.fireAuth.signInWithRedirect(this.googleProvider);
  }
}
```

This is my app.component:

```
[all imports here]

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Home;
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        this.nav.setRoot(Home);
      } else {
        this.nav.setRoot(Menu);
      }
    });

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

And this is my home.ts:

```
[some imports here]

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class Home {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authData: AuthData) {}

  registerUserWithGoogle() {
    this.authData.googleSignin();
  }
}
```

So when i try to sign in with Google from home.html (that its a view on app.html) to menu.html i got some weird behaviour. I have some screenshots.

app.html:

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

home.html:

```
<ion-content class="home">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-icon">
      <img src="assets/img/logotipo.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ion-button block color="danger" class="google-btn" (click)="registerUserWithGoogle()">
    Log In with Google
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

This is what i get when i log in:

[image: pic1]

And if i click on the arrow i get this:

[image: pic2]

but now im not able to click on sidemenu and i dont know if its for nesting two ion view or something else.

Thank you

Comment: signInWithRedirect and signInWithPopup are not yet supported in ionic/cordova environments. You will have to use a Cordova plugin for google sign-in to get the Google OAuth token and the use firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, googleAccessToken)) to sign in with that credential.

Comment: okey thank you ill try asap

Comment: hi i try this https://javebratt.com/firebase-3-email-auth/ email and password auth instead of google auth and it does the same so its maybe cause of the app? maybe nested views problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the comments so this is now a 2 part question:

1) For Google Auth, the `signInWithRedirect()` and `signInWithPopUp()` methods don't work in cordova/ionic apps *yet*.

You'll need to use the Google native plugin to get the login credentials and then you can pass them to `firebase.auth.signInWithCredentials()`

2) About the bug sending you to the HomePage:

There's a weird bug in Ionic's navCtrl that isn't pushing the page after it returns with the user in:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (!user) {
    this.nav.setRoot(Home);
  } else {
    this.nav.setRoot(Menu);
  }
});
```

I got that working by simply declaring `rootPage: any = Menu;` and then doing this instead:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (!user) {
    this.nav.setRoot(Home);
  }
});
```