# Ion-menu is not displaying after login with google

Tags: angular, ionic3

This is the code for google login.In my code when the user login as a admin for the first time showing the alert with you are new in button 'ok' handler using

```
 this.navCtrl.push(AdminSideMenuPage);

  googleAuthentication(){
    localStorage.clear();
    this.loading.present();
//--- For windows G+ login
    if (this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider().setCustomParameters({
      'prompt': 'select_account'})).then(res =>{
        this.userdata={
            email:res.user.email,
            image:res.user.photoURL,
            displayName: res.user.displayName
        }  
        localStorage.setItem('LoginStatus','true');
        localStorage.setItem('gmaildata', JSON.stringify(this.userdata));
        this.login(res.user.email);
      }).catch(err=>{
        //console.log("err "+JSON.stringify(err))
        this.loading.dismiss();
      })
    }
//--- For Android G+ login 
    else {
      var options = {'prompt':'select_account'};
      this.googlePlus.login(options)
      .then(res => {
        this.userdata={
            email:res.email,
            image:res.imageUrl,
            displayName:res.displayName
        }  
        localStorage.setItem('gmaildata', JSON.stringify(this.userdata));
        this.login(res.email);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        //console.log("errg+"+JSON.stringify(err))
        this.loading.dismiss();
      })
    }
  }

  login(gmail){

    if(!this.docStyle){
      // Doctor
      localStorage.setItem('LoginStatus','Doctrue');
      this.Receptionists.subscribe(data => {
        var user = false;
        for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++)
        {
          if(gmail == data[i].receptionistsnames){
            localStorage.setItem('Adminid',data[i].adminid);
            user = true;
          }
        }
        if(user)
        {
          this.loading.dismiss();
          if(this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb'))
            this.navCtrl.push(SideMenuPage);
          else
            this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
        }
        else{
          this.loading.dismiss();
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({title: 'Invalid Receptionist',message: 'You Are Not a Registered User.',
            buttons: [{text: 'Ok',
              handler: () => {
                if (this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) 
                  this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
                else 
                  this.googlePlus.logout();
                window.location.reload();
              }
            }]
          });
          alert.present();
        }
      })
    }
    else{
      //Admin
       localStorage.setItem('LoginStatus','Admintrue');
       this.admin.subscribe(data => {
        var user = false;
        for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++)
        {
          if( gmail == data[i].email)
            user = true;
        }
        if(user){
          this.navCtrl.push(AdminSideMenuPage);
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }
        else
        {
          this.loading.dismiss();
          //this.navCtrl.setRoot(AdminSideMenuPage);
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({title: 'Admin Login',message: 'you are New.',
            buttons: [{text: 'Ok',
              handler: () => {
                this.startdate= new Date();
                this.enddate=this.startdate.setDate( this.startdate.getDate() + 50 );
                this.admin.push({
                      adminid:gmail,
                      email:gmail,
                      startdate:Date.now(),
                      enddate:this.enddate,
                     })
                     alert.dismiss().then(() => {
                      this.navCtrl.push(AdminSideMenuPage);
                      this.navCtrl.pop().then(data => {
                        this.navCtrl.push(AdminSideMenuPage);
                      //  this.navCtrl.setRoot(AdminSideMenuPage);
                      //  this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
                      });
                    });
                    //return false;
                  //    let navTransition = alert.dismiss();
                  //    navTransition.then(() => {
                  //     this.navCtrl.setRoot(AdminSideMenuPage);
                  //    });
                  //  return false; 
              }
            }]
          });
          alert.present();
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

After Login with google ion side menu is not displaying, but when refresh side menu is displaying.

I am using `this.navCtrl.push(AdminSideMenuPage);` in `login.ts` file.

I have tried

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
}
```

But ended with no result.

How to display the side menu after login with out refreshing the page?

Comment: Can you please provide your code ?

Comment: Is this work with other login ?

Comment: for any login it is not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to try `persistent="true"` in your `ion-menu` item.

Use sample code as follows in you `app.html`

```
 <ion-menu persistent="true" [content]="content">...</ion-menu>
```

Actually By default, `menus`, and specifically their menu toggle buttons in the `navbar`, only show on the `root page` within its `NavController`. For example, on `Page 1` the `menu toggle` will show in the `navbar`. However, when navigating to `Page 2`, because it is not the `root Page` for that `NavController`, the menu toggle will not show in the `navbar`.

Not showing the menu toggle button in the `navbar` is commonly seen within native apps after navigating past the root Page. However, it is still possible to always show the menu toggle button in the navbar by setting `persistent="true"` on the `ion-menu` component.

If above solutions not working for you then simply declaring `rootPage: any = AdminSideMenuPage;` and then use following:

```
 if (!user) {
   this.nav.setRoot(Home);
  }
```

Please check more details from [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/menu-toggle-button-in-all-pages/104605/3), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562317/ionic-2-google-signin-with-firebase?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211533/ionic-3-refresh-side-menu-after-login?rq=1).

Hopes this will help you !!